# Reset scroll to (0,0) when clicking/pressing on link to current route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, framer-motion

I have a React app. If the user is on route `/gallery/images` and selects a link (`<a>` or `<Link>` from `react-router-dom` for example) on the same page that goes to the **same** route as is currently mounted, how can I listen for those events and smoothly scroll back to the top of the page.

Imagine another scenario: the user is on the home page, scrolls down a bit, then clicks on the website logo. How can I listen for those events to scroll the user back up.

Comment: can you add a sample e.g. that you tried ? you can link the sandbox link ... (you can use codesandbox / stackblitz) save code, share link

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how accurate it is, but you can define a counter state, and increment that state when clicked (your logo etc). Then you can bind useEffect in this state and write `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`